# AutoIt recent files menu

Tags: autoit

I have a user's choice which is set as recent files:

```
$loc = FileSelectFolder("Choose file location...", "\")
$file = FileOpenDialog("Choose file...", $loc, "Jar Files (*.jar*)")
GUICtrlCreateMenuItem($file, $recentfilesmenu)
```

I have tried to get the information from it through:

```
IniWrite("C:\Config.ini", "Recent", "Recent", GUICtrlRead($recentfilesmenu))
```

But it only gives me the number 68. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number `68` is the controlID of the menu.

You need to use [`_GUICtrlMenu_GetItemText`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_GUICtrlMenu_GetItemText.htm) to read the text of the menu item:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GuiMenu.au3>

$hGui = GUICreate('Read Menu Item', 400, 300)
$mnuFile = GUICtrlCreateMenu('&File')
$mnuFileExit = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem('Exit', $mnuFile)
GUISetState()

; read the text of the menu item
$hMenu = _GUICtrlMenu_GetMenu($hGui)
$sText = _GUICtrlMenu_GetItemText($hMenu, $mnuFileExit, False)
MsgBox(0, 'Menu item text', $sText)

While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    If $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Or $msg = $mnuFileExit Then ExitLoop
WEnd
```

This outputs: Exit

---

**Update**
To pick up Matt's suggestion you can also make use of the advanced parameter for [`GUICtrlRead`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlRead.htm) which is much shorter:

```
IniWrite("C:\Config.ini", "Recent", "Recent", GUICtrlRead($recentfilesmenu, 1))
```

Comment: @mrt Thanks. I got it to work. I just wonder. How should I get it to add the past item to the list. Instead of showing the current item in the list, How can I get the item I chose earlier. Maybe add so it can shows several items and not overwriting if the item already exists?

Comment: @EpicKnarvik97, there are plenty of examples where people have done this before. Usually by setting a limit (say 9 items) and storing them in an array. Search the forums for more.